# App launcher to reload from beginning in Android

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have created app to act like an home launcher. So when user clicks on the home button I get Complete action using Launcher or my app's name say for example "myhomelauncher".

When I click on home button and click myhomelauncher my application loads everything from first perfectly fine. Now when I am in the second screen in my application say I am looking at activity 2 in my app and now I click on Home button and click myhomelauncher I endup getting the same activity 2 windows it is not reloading. (It should reload and show up activity 1 rather than 2)

I have seen lot of apps that can reload everytime I click their launcher. Why not mine?

Here is what I have done in my manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyLauncher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I am not sure where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look into the documentation - what can be of interest to your problem are the following settings:

- [android:clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear)
- [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

I would suspect setting `android:launchMode` to `singleTask` could solve your problem, altough be careful which side effects this will cause.

So:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyLauncher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Look up `launchMode`. But be careful, with great power, comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

This is the relevant section in a menifest that seems to work for me.  Note that I have put **singleInstance** in the launch mode because I don't want more than one of my app, ever.

```
<application  android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".usbEffects" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"                
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```